# Newbie asking how to exit while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to python, and don't really have experience with coding. So, i'm trying to do this kind of exercise using functions and I've tried different approaches but I just can't exit loop. So, this works just how it supposed to work, except it doesn't exit while - loop. And I don't understand why that break doesn't work

```py
valinta = ()

def main():
    valinta = input("Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): ")
    if len(valinta) <= (5):
       tulostus = ("Oletustulostus")
    elif valinta == ("lopeta"):
        tulostus=("lopetit")
    elif len(valinta) >= (6):
            tulostus = valinta

    tulostin(tulostus)

def tulostin(tulostus):
    print(tulostus)

while valinta !=("lopeta"):
    if valinta == ("lopeta"):
       break
    elif __name__ == "__main__":
        main()`
```

I also tried chancing "lopeta" to (0), but with all variations loop starts

```
Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): asdf
Oletustulostus
Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): asfgghhj
asfgghhj
Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): lopeta
lopetit
Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa):
```

Comment: Without looking too deeply... You have a loop that executes while a condition is false and you exit condition is if the condition is true, which it never will be...

Comment: `main` does not change the value of the global variable `valinta`; it sets the value of a *local* variable instead. Don't use globals at all; `main` should *return* a value that can be compared against `"lopeta"` instead.

Comment: The invocation of `main` inside the loop doesn't make sense, and completely defeats the purpose of checking `__name__`.  The test for `valinta` inside the loop also doesn't make sense since it will clearly always be false.  That said, the problem is that `velinta` is a local variable inside `main`, so the global value never changes, i.e. it is always `()`.  If you really want to change it in `main`, then you need to declare it global.

Comment: BTW (not directly related to your problem), you don't need to use parentheses everywhere and even if it's syntactically ok, it's confusing. You can perfectly do `if len(valinta) <= 5:` or `tulostus = "Oletustulostus"`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want something like the following:

```
def ask_input():
    valinta = input("Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): ")
    if len(valinta) <= (5):
        tulostus = "Oletustulostus"
    elif valinta == "lopeta":
        tulostus = "lopetit"
    elif len(valinta) >= 6:
        tulostus = valinta

    tulostin(tulostus)

    return tulostus

def tulostin(tulostus):
    print(tulostus)

def main():
    tulostus = ""
    while tulostus != "lopetit":
        tulostus = ask_input()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output is:

```
Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): short
Oletustulostus
Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): much longer than needed
much longer than needed
Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): lopeta
lopetit
```

See if you can see how it works as I think it does what you're looking for but my Finnish isn't great!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I meant this to do. I'm trying to learn from this, and I know this is silly question: in while loop, while condition is True, main calls for ask_input. but when condition is False, it exits loop and next line in code is again call for main. To be true, that whole if __name__.. line is something that were told in material, that you have to put it in code, I haven't truly understood how it works..

Comment: You don't actually need the `if __name__` line unless you want to load the code into an another program, perhaps a test suite.  For a simple program, you could just drop the `if ...` line and have the 'main()' not indented, or even not have main() as a function at all.  I'd suggest that you find a 'learn python' course online and work through a course to get the hang of a few things as they'll explain a lot of what I think you want to know.  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments. As can be seen, I'm just starting to trying to learn coding, and I haven't got really far. Just to clarify, why I did it originally that way: had to declare 'valinta' somehow, and for exit condition in loop, it is just something I tried (but didn't work), because I thought that 'while != ("lopeta")' would only need 'if **name**....', and main wouldn't start again while condition wouldn't match.

But so, my problem were variable declared in wrong place. I still have lot to learn, but I guess I have to start somewhere

```
def ask_input():
valinta = input("Anna syöte (Lopeta lopettaa): ")
if len(valinta) <= (5):
    tulostus = "Oletustulostus"
elif valinta == "Lopeta":
    tulostus = ()
    return None
elif len(valinta) >= 6:
    tulostus = valinta
tulostin(tulostus)
return tulostus

def tulostin(tulostus):
print(tulostus)
def main():
tulostus = ""
while tulostus != None:
    tulostus = ask_input()
if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

So, here is how I managed to do this. I had problems, because 'Lopeta' were printed, and for assignment it should just had to exit loop.

Just be be clear, I used to be paramedic and now I'm engineering student, but not for information technology. I have opportunity to take introduction to python online course,just wanted to try if I could figure out some basic coding.

Comment: None of your definitions of functions have proper indentation. Indentation has syntactic meaning in python, is not optional or flexible.

Comment: I don't think is a good practice to define a function that only runs another function, like your function `tulostin` that only calls `print`. If you want to assign a new name to print, it's as easy as to do `tulostin = print` (note there are no parentheses here).

Comment: Yes, watch that indentation - it's extremely important in python.  And don't use TAB, use spaces.

Comment: When you're building a program, it is often useful to have a function that simply calls another function if it is going to be built into something more functional later - perhaps appending the output to a file etc.